# How do I change the text on a label after question number 11?

Tags: c#

How do I change the text of label 'levellabel' when question 11 is answered?

```
  if (questionNumber == 11)
            {
                QuizForm quiz = new QuizForm();
                quiz.level1timer.Enabled = true;
                quiz.levellabel.Text = "Level 1";
            }
        }
```

Comment: What about above code?

Answer (score -1):

After questionNumber 11 would result in this code:

```
if (questionNumber > 11)
```